# Scala compile server - VM warning

Tags: java, scala, vm-implementation

I'm using ***java*** + ***scala*** (with ***sbt***) at one project.

Language info:

```
nazar@desktop:~⟫ java -version
java version "1.8.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.5-b02, mixed mode)
nazar@desktop:~⟫ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.4 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

When I'm running any `main()` I got a strange warning prompt:

[image: warning]

I couldn't figure out this behaviour.

**UPDATE:**

I checked `sbt` options it has the same behaviour:

```
nazar@desktop:~⟫ sbt -version
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
```

Thanks for so fast explanation new features for Java 1.8!

***But how to solve occurrence of `MaxPermSise` warning?***

here is content of `idea.vmoptions`:

```
-server
-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd
```

Eclipse has `eclipse.ini`:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
-/home/nazar/optional/java/jdk1.8.0/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

**UPDATE2**

I deleted from both configuration files all lines which contain `MaxPermSize`.

But this error warning keep arising (when `main()` is running, and run `sbt -version` at the terminal).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PermGen management has changed in Java 8. IIRC, it's managed directly in the OS memory. Consequently, limitations and customizations used until then are not available anymore. Particularly, MaxPermSize does not have any meaning anymore. I suppose intellij does have this option by default when it runs a sbt application.

You'll find more information about changes in Java 8 here : http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/milestones

Comment: Did you mean to say *MaxPermSize does not have any* **meaning** *anymore*?

Comment: That's what I've understood, yes. There's no memory for permgen in the jvm memory anymore, so there's no need to customize it.

Comment: @Agemen Really tricky changes. How to solve this issue, now?

Comment: @nazar_art Do we have to spell it out for you?  Just remove that option if you don't want to see the warning.

Comment: @Agemen I did it for both IDE. But this warning keep arising. What is missed?